# Extended Ascii codes incomplete DART? No character from 128 to 160

Tags: ascii, dart

I created a small piece of code to print the extended ASCII characters in DART but it seems the ones between 128 and 160 are blank.

```
  PrintExtendedASCII(){
  var listCodes = new List();
  for (var i = 128; i < 256  ; i++) {
   listeCodes.add(i);
  }
  var list = new String.fromCharCodes(listCodes);
  print(list);
}
```

It only prints :  ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ

Is there something different about the extended ASCII characters in DART?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "extended ASCII" in Dart. The character codes you are using in the code example are not ASCII - they are [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) code points. For code points 0-127, the character codes match ASCII exactly. The block you are missing, from 128 to 160 (0x80 to 0x9F), is all non-printable control characters.

Here is a table of [Unicode code points for the 0x000-0xFFF block](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF). If you look carefully, the order of characters exactly matches the string printed on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!